# Intro MP3 file with SHOUTcast

Tags: stream, shoutcast, internet-radio

I have a PHP MP3 file which changes every time it is loaded, and plays a different advert, what I would like is away or is there away to play that before the SHOUTcast stream as the SHOUTcast intro file.

I personally dont really want to put it into flash or create custom playlist files but more would like SHOUTcast to fetch an intro file from a URL address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the SHOUTcast configuration doesn't allow this directly.

However, you can easily accomplish what you need by having a script pick a new intro file every few seconds or so.  Then you can either write that  MP3 to the file configured in SHOUTcast, or create a symlink and update it.

Comment: Thanks but if say every 5 minutes I write that mp3 to the config file in shoutcast dont I need to re-boot the stream

Comment: @RussellHarrower, No, that's not what I'm saying.  Leave the config file alone, pointed at `somefile.mp3` or whatever.  Your script will write your updated MP3 files, replacing the file contents of `somefile.mp3`.  The SHOUTcast config won't need to be changed, just the MP3 file itself.  Does that make sense?  If your MP3 files are of any reasonable size, I suggest making the symlink, as switching the symlink is very fast.  I don't know what happens to SHOUTcast if you are writing to a file that it tries to read.  I suspect there is a lock, but I am not sure.